# movetoios: whatsapp deleted all other files?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, file-transfer, ios

I have recently bought a second-hand iphone. Coming from a Samsung Galaxy A6, I wanted to transfer my whatsapp database to my new phone. After some attempts, I finally succeeded and transferred everything except movies. I assumed that these files would still be on my A6 but when I looked in the whatsapp media directory, I could not find what I was looking for.

I do not know how the program works or if this question should be in the apple exchange site but I hope to find out what happens when you use the MovetoiOS tool with the files you did not select for transfer and where I should be able to find these files. Obviously, just running whatsapp on old A6 won't work as whatsapp is now configured on my iphone.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally delete the movie files, perhaps from 3rd-party app like Google Photos or other gallery/file manager apps?

Comment: i'm absolutely sure I did not do that.

Comment: I'm now just wondering: when I remove all databases and reinstall whatsapp on my A6 again: it will download an old backup from my google drive. The movies should be in there too I guess. But I'm affraid I might cause trouble on my iPhone. But extracting the backup in my google drive might be a solution?